# Thermal Energy in a pV diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, ideal-gas

I'm studying for an exam in thermodynamics and therefore going through old exams, but I am stuck on one assignment.

> One kilomole of ideal monoatomic gas under standard conditions is
>   processed from condition 1 to condition 2 in two different ways: $1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2$ and $1 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2$. Find the ratio of the thermal energies that must be transferred to the gas in these processes.

[image]

I tried to solve this by first using the first law of thermodynamics

$dU=dQ+dW$

where U is the internal energy, Q the thermal energy and W the work done by the gas.

The work can be obtained from

$dW=-pdV$

which in this case means the area under the graph

For the different pathways we get the following work:

$1 \rightarrow 3, \Delta W=0$

$3 \rightarrow 2, \Delta W=2p_0V_0$

$1 \rightarrow 4, \Delta W=p_0V_0$

$4 \rightarrow 2, \Delta W=0$

Since the gas is monoatomic and ideal $U$ can be calculated from

$U=3Nk_BT/2=3p_0V_0/2$

Plugging this into the first law of thermodynamics would give me

$1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2: Q=1.5p_0V_0-2p_0V_0=-1,5p_0V_0$

$1 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2: Q=1.5 p_0V_0-p_0V_0=0.5p_0V_0$

However the correct answer is

$1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2: Q=1.5p_0V_0+5p_0V_0=6.5p_0V_0$

$1 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2: Q=2.5p_0V_0+3p_0V_0=5.5p_0V_0$

What have I done wrong? It seems like I have missed some terms in $U$ but where would they come from?

Comment: you should take care of your signs, $dW=-pdV$ but $\Delta W, p,\Delta V>0$. There is obviously a mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for First Law of Thermodynamics can be written in the form (starting from the equation you wrote with $dW=-pdV$)

$$dQ=dU+pdV$$ where $dU=C_v dT$.Here for mono atomic ideal gas $C_v=\frac{3}{2}K_BT$. 
Using equation of state for ideal gas one gets $$ dU=\frac{3}{2}[Vdp+pdV]$$
So $$1\rightarrow3:dU=\frac{3}{2}p_0V_0,pdV=0$$
   $$3\rightarrow2:dU=3p_0V_0,pdV=2p_0V_0$$
$$1\rightarrow4:dU=\frac{3}{2}p_0V_0,pdV=p_0V_0$$
$$4\rightarrow2:dU=3p_0V_0,pdV=0$$ So we see that the thermal energy for the two different path is 
   $$1\rightarrow3\rightarrow 2:dQ=(\frac{3}{2}+3+2)p_0V_0=6.5p_0V_0$$
   $$1\rightarrow4\rightarrow 2:dQ=(1+\frac{3}{2}+3)p_0V_0=5.5p_0V_0$$
Note:Internal energy is a state function which means it does not depends on which path you choose.You can see here in both path $dU$ is equal.

Comment: In your calculation you took $dW=-pdV$ but while calculating $dW$ you used $dW=pdV$

Comment: Thank you! I also see that I made the wrong assumption $Nk_BT=pV=p_0V_0$! It of course needs to be calculated for every step in the process!